# Yii2 - Why ajax change page in Listview with Pjax not working properly

Tags: yii2

I used listview with pjax block and this is my view page:

```
<div class="main-video">
    <div>نمایش</div>
    <div id="data">
        <?php
        $model = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => FileInfos::find()->where(['type' => 2])->orderBy(['id'=>SORT_DESC]),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 15,
            ],
        ]);
        Pjax::begin([
            'id'=> 'id-pjax',
            'enablePushState' => false, // to disable push state
            'enableReplaceState' => false, // to disable replace state,
            'timeout'=> 999999999
        ]);
        if(isset($model))
            echo ListView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $model,
                'itemView' => '/partials/_item',
                'viewParams' => ['typeName' => 'video'],
            ]);
        Pjax::end();
        ?>

    </div>
    <button id="btn-show">نمایش</button>
</div>
```

And this is my action controller code:

```
public function actionVideo()
{
    return $this->render('video');
}
```

After click on next page, it's reload on entire page.

in network tab of inspect element, I see two request calls:

1 - video?page=2&per-page=15&_pjax=%23id-pjax

2 - video?page=2&per-page=15

First request no have any response and second request have the rendered view page which reloads to that.

Whats wrong in my code?

How can I fix this issue for have ajax request call for changing page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article helped me: https://riptutorial.com/yii2/example/16529/how-to-use-pjax,
So it solved by changing pjax begin block with this code:

```
    Pjax::begin([
        'id'=> 'id-pjax-'.uniqid(),
        'enablePushState' => false, // to disable push state
        'enableReplaceState' => false, // to disable replace state,
        'timeout'=> 999999999,
        'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']
    ]);
```